# Storing 2 numbers in a sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, sequences

I need to store 2 variables. They represent the order they were pressed in. For example "tab2" with value 2, and after that the "tab1" with value 1 etc.

I tried to store them with

```
  window.ACTIVE_NUMBER;
  window.LAST_NUMBER;
```

and some global functions, but It's always telling me that LAST_NUMBER is undefined.

Is there perhaps an easier way, like with tables?

I need the data from the clicks to animate some stuff later on. 
If the 1st number is bigger than the 2nd, it'll be different than if it's smaller.

The fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gfsmhy37/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a '#' on your jQuery call:

```
window.outputBefore = function(x) {
    $("#output-before").text(x); // You were missing the # here
};
```

Also, some other things:
Change

```
  window.ACTIVE_NUMBER;
  window.LAST_NUMBER;
```

To:

```
var ACTIVE_NUMBER;
var LAST_NUMBER;
```

Also, you need to change LAST_NUMBER before you update ACTIVE_NUMBER, that way it remembers what ACTIVE_NUMBER was before its current value.

```
 window.checker = function() {
   LAST_NUMBER = ACTIVE_NUMBER; // Added this line
    var foundnumber = parseInt($(".tool.active").index() + 1);
    ACTIVE_NUMBER = foundnumber;
  };
```

And then in your click function, you need to output LAST_NUMBER:

```
 $(".tool").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      console.log("It is already active.");
    } else {
      $(".tool").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      checker();
      outputBefore(ACTIVE_NUMBER); // Add this line
      output(LAST_NUMBER); 
    }
  });
```

And put semi-colons after all of your functions.

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //    global variables
  var ACTIVE_NUMBER;
  var LAST_NUMBER;

  //    global functions
  window.output = function(x) {
    $("#output").text(x);
  };

  window.outputBefore = function(x) {
    $("#output-before").text(x);
  };

  window.checker = function() {
   LAST_NUMBER = ACTIVE_NUMBER;
    var foundnumber = parseInt($(".tool.active").index() + 1);
    ACTIVE_NUMBER = foundnumber;
  };

  //    the starting value
  //    if(LAST_NUMBER == undefined){
  //        LAST_NUMBER = 1;
  //    }

  checker();
output(ACTIVE_NUMBER);
outputBefore(LAST_NUMBER);





  //    Changes applied onclick event
  $(".tool").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      console.log("It is already active.");
    } else {
      $(".tool").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      checker();
      outputBefore(ACTIVE_NUMBER);
      output(LAST_NUMBER);
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

LAST_NUMBER is always undefined because you never define it :)

You would need to call window.outputBefore in your click function by doing something like var foundnumber = parseInt($(".tool.active").index() + 1); before you change the values.

You are also missing a # on your $("output-before").text(x); 
Should be => ($("#output-before").text(x);)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned LAST_NUMBER variable and jQuery selector mistake... I hope this is what you are looking for 
https://jsfiddle.net/gfsmhy37/3/

```
window.outputBefore = function(x) {
$("#output-before").text(x);
}

window.checker = function() {
var foundnumber = parseInt($(".tool.active").index() + 1);
LAST_NUMBER =  ACTIVE_NUMBER;
ACTIVE_NUMBER = foundnumber;
}
```